# Trouble setting input value to ng-model property [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following input field:

```
 <span class="dropdown-text">
    Col <input type="text" value='tile.col' size="1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">     
</span>
```

I'm trying to have the value of the input field be occupied by a .col property in a "selected tiles property" (i cannot provide full code) but when I open up dev tools I see the following:

```
<tile class="ng-scope gridster-item" row="0" col="0" ng-repeat= "tile in selectedTiles"> ....</tile>
```

When I run the code nothing appears in the input box, because it's not finding the scope I'm presuming, any ideas on what I can try from this code?

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straight forward depending on what your selectedTiles object looks like.

```
<span class="dropdown-text">
Col <input type="text" value='tile.col' size="1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="selectedTile.WHATYOUWANTDISPLAYED">
```

If you could elaborate on your question, could help answer a bit better.